# does pull merge with local repository?

Tags: git, merge, repository, pull

In git, if I commit something to my local repository, and then I do a pull and merge with my code, does it merge with my local repository as well? If not, then what happens when I push to the master repository? Does it overwrite with my commits or does it merge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+merge